# What size circuit breaker is required for a GE model JBP68HKWW range?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, range

What size circuit breaker is required for a GE model JBP68HKWW range?

Comment: What size is the wire for the branch circuit?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the wire going to the range.

If the wire is 8 AWG you can only use a 40A breaker, regardless of what the range's instructions may tell you.

If it is 6 AWG, you should use 40A or 50A depending on what the range's instructions say to use.

***While you're in there...*** this is a very good time to make sure you are using the modern, grounded 4-wire connection including a NEMA 14 plug/socket if it uses a plug.  The old 3-wire connection is hazardous, as any problem with the neutral wire will electrify the chassis of the range.  No kidding, and this problem has a body count.

It's especially a shame if the house is wired with modern /3 cable +ground, but someone downgraded it because their used range had a 3-prong connection.   If it doesn't have a ground now, the rules now allow you to add just a ground wire, either back to the panel or anywhere else with a 10AWG ground wire back to the panel.

Comment: Can you cite the body count. I hear these claims all the times but in 40+ years have never found a death, shocks yes and 4 wire is the best way but I would bet there are more than 50million 3 wire ranges out there and I have never seen or heard of an actual death.

Comment: @EdBeal Nor will you.  There's a big difference between "miswired" and "wired correctly but an ordinary honest failure happens".  People are inculcated into the idea that the latter can't kill.  As such, reporters never report NEMA 10 electrocutions as "correctly wired, failed" but rather as "miswired".  And the institutional stakeholders have no incentive to correct the record: remember it started with a compromise between appliance makers and NFPA so they're out... and of course trial lawyers vastly prefer the "miswired" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the power ratings for your particular range.

POWER / RATINGS

Amp Rating at 208V  40

Amp Rating at 240V  40

KW Rating at 208V   8.3

KW Rating at 240V   11.0

So a 40A circuit would work and a #8 conductor is good for 50A according to 2014 NEC Table 310.15 (B)(16), that makes you good to go. I should warn you though that a standard range circuit installed in any residence in the US is a 50A breaker and a #6 conductor circuit with a NEMA 14-50R receptacle. So you might consider meeting everyone else's standards. That way if you ever upgrade your range or sold the house, it would cause less complications down the road.

Comment: This is it...  You should wire to what is common in a kitchen in your area.  Also, you probably can't find a socket or plug rated for 40A because 50A is the defacto standard and you can't put a 50A receptacle on a 40A circuit.

Comment: @JPhi1618 -- there are no 40A receptacles in common use, so you're stuck with a 50A receptacle on a 40A circuit (the NEC specifically calls this out in Table 210.21(B)(3))

Answer (score 0):

A 40A appliance on a dedicated circuit usually needs a breaker of at least 40A and wire gauge to match.

See [What amp breaker for 20 Amp electrical oven and 40 Amp electrical range on same circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/47939/2815)