# Can this cooktop and wall oven go on the same circuit?

Tags: electrical, kitchens

Here is the link to the cooktop:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/LG-30-in-Radiant-Smooth-Surface-Electric-Cooktop-in-Black-with-5-Elements-and-SmoothTouch-Controls-LCE3010SB/202665321

Here is the link for the oven:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/LG-4-7-cu-ft-Smart-Single-Electric-Wall-Oven-with-Fan-Convection-Air-Fry-in-PrintProof-in-Stainless-Steel-WSEP4723F/324906049

The existing wires are 6/2 to the junction, then 10/2 coming out to the cooktop and 8 gauge wire going to the oven. This single circuit is on a 50 amp breaker.

The oven will be wired in a 3 wire setup with the nuetral and ground bonded. The cooktop will have the bare copper going to ground and white and black to hot

Comment: Do the instructions  for each call for dedicated circuits?

Comment: I imagine you have the oven and cooktop mixed up for the wire sizes.  the cooktop takes 40 amps and the oven is plus 25 amps, so you are looking at 70 amps for the both of them.  A second circuit for the oven sounds better.

Comment: Bonding neutral and ground for either appliance is illegal and dangerous.

Comment: @crip659 The NEC actually has special rules for cooktops and ovens that are more favorable than simply adding amperages. They recognize that every burner and heating element will likely not cycle on at the same time.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Joining an appliance’s ground and neutral wires to a circuit’s neutral is technically *not* illegal if the instructions allow it (these do) and the circuit was legal when installed (i.e. pre-1996). It is always dangerous though.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47939/what-amp-breaker-for-20-amp-electrical-oven-and-40-amp-electrical-range-on-same

Answer (score 2):

No, these cannot share a circuit. The instructions for the cooktop state the following:

> A 3-wire or 4-wire single-phase 120/240 or 120/208 volt, 60 Hz AC-only electrical supply is required on a **separate circuit** fused on both sides of the line (time-delay fuse or circuit breaker is recommended).

The bold is mine. The instructions for the oven state:

> This wall oven must be supplied with the proper voltage and frequency, and connected to an **individual**, properly grounded branch circuit, protected by a circuit breaker or fuse.

Since code requires you to follow the instructions provided by the manufacturer, you can't put these devices on the same circuit. Other brand devices may offer you that option, so it's worth looking through installation manuals if this is a significant requirement for your installation.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for the cooktop states a dedicated circuit is required and it needs a 40 amp breaker with #8AWG wire. So no, the two appliances can't be on the same circuit. You might consider a sub panel.

Comment: What exactly will the sub panel do?

Comment: @user170817  If you wire the sub panel at 70 amps, you can put a 40 and 30 amp breakers in it and have two circuits, instead of needing to go all the way back to the main panel.

Comment: Note that if you add a subpanel it will need clearance, which most people don't have in their kitchens. You can't hide it away in a cabinet or anything like that.

Comment: Wouldn’t I still need to run a 4 gauge wire anyways to the sub panel?

Comment: @user170817  It will depend which way is easier to run wires, two circuits from the main panel, or one big wire to sub panel.  If main panel is full, a sub panel helps with giving more breaker spaces(not more power).  It depends too much on how your house is wired to say which way is better for you.