# What circuit does the samsung NE58H9970WS induction range need?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, oven

I tried looking through samsungs install manuals. The manually helpfully says the oven should only plug into the circuit with the correct amps - however it doesn't say what those amps should be.

I did find on home depots website it says 40amps - but thats the ONLY site i've found that mentions the specific amps. A discussion on houzz seems to think when you add up all the elements and features on the oven that draw power, that you'd need at least 50 amps.

Would 40 amps be enough?

Comment: There should be a label on the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation (PDF)](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/NE58H9970WS/AA#) says

> Use only a 3-conductor or a 4-conductor UL-listed range cord...

Range cords typically have NEMA 14-50 Plugs on the end, so you'll need a NEMA 14-50 receptacle to plug the range into.

The documentation also says.

> A range cord rated at 40 amps with 125/250 minimum volt range is required. A 50 amp range cord is not recommended but if used, it should be marked for use with nominal 1 3⁄8” diameter connection openings.

And that the range is rated at 8,750  -  16,500 watts, when connected to a 120/240 volt 3 wire circuit. National Electrical Code says that you'll need at least a 40 ampere breaker, and 8 AWG copper conductors and 10 AWG copper ground.

Here's some [further reading](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/37004/33) explaining the actual code.